# Is there a CDN for AffixJs bootstrap library?

Tags: github, cdn

I don't want the entire bootstrap.js library.

Just affix.

GitHub Source: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/js/affix.js

Comment: just found this https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v3.3.7/js/affix.js

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use only affix , use this cdn

> https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v3.3.7/js/affix.js